# How can I make the Sign Column show up all the time even if no Signs have been added to it?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I've just added the [Git Gutter plugin](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) for Vim which shows lines added/modified/deleted according to `git diff`. It uses the `Sign Column` to show characters next to each line.

At the moment the column appears on save, which is quite jarring. I'd prefer the column to always show, even if empty.

How can I make Sign Column always visible?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Starting with Vim 7.4.2201, you can do:

```
:set signcolumn=yes
```

Cp. [`:help 'signcolumn'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27signcolumn%27). For older Vim versions, you have to define a dummy sign and place it into the current buffer:

```
:sign define dummy
:execute 'sign place 9999 line=1 name=dummy buffer=' . bufnr('')
```

Comment: To make it work in every new buffer you open, put both `autocmd BufEnter * sign define dummy` and `autocmd BufEnter * execute 'sign place 9999 line=1 name=dummy buffer=' . bufnr('')` in your vimrc.

Comment: Seems outdated as `set signcolumn=yes` does the trick without shenanigans.

Comment: @cprn: You're right; I've added that to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you as well, removing my answer from the bottom then. Cheers!

Answer (score 25):

For vim-gitgutter specifically, you can also set the following variable in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:gitgutter_sign_column_always = 1
```

**UPDATE**

The plugin will now issue a warning to remove the above line and instead use:

```
set signcolumn="yes"
```

Comment: Thanks, that option must of been added after this question was posted. Useful to know though.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that the commit which added it was made on 14 March 2013 — exactly two weeks after your question!

Comment: While working on something else I recently poked around inside the GitGutter source, and I noticed that setting this variable forces the display of the sign column in exactly the same way as the accepted answer to this question — by setting a dummy sign.

Comment: btw, for me it was `set signcolumn=yes` *without* the quotes

Comment: **Note that `gitgutter_sign_column_always` doesn't exist anymore since 2019 https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/commit/afe94ede1bac4587ca55d8c4fe182ca49ee0b180**

Answer (score 8):

While the little dance defining a sign and placing it works ok, a more elegant alternative that works well for me is:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * setlocal signcolumn=yes
```

And if there are certain filetypes that are not supposed to have the column:

```
autocmd FileType tagbar,nerdtree setlocal signcolumn=no
```

Comment: Error detected while processing BufReadPost Auto commands for "*":
E518: Unknown option: signcolumn=yes

Comment: You need a newer version of vim, @brandonjones. I'm not sure when `signcolumn` was added, but it's not there in 7.2 and it's there in 8.0. I don't remember seeing it in 7.4, but it may be there. It's present in current versions of both Vim and Neovim.